# PI and e constants in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, math, visual-studio-2013, calculator

I'm trying to build a calculator in Visual Studio, in C#, and I want to use these important mathematical constants. I declare them:

```
public constant double PI;
public constant double e;
```

But it shows an error for these declarations:

> A const field requires a value to be provided.

What should I do, guys?

Comment: I vote to close it because... oh, I don't know why really, it's already answered in the error message. And if the question about using `pi` and `e` constants - than it should be reformulated.

Answer (score 12):

Exactly what the error says, you need to supply a value.

That said, there is already constants for most math function in the System.Math namespace.

So you can use:

```
System.Math.PI
System.Math.E
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math_fields(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide value during declaring constant variable

Try like this

```
 public const double PI=3.1416;
```

instead of

```
 public constant double PI;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever declaring a `const` variable it must be done with the declaration itself so you need to declare them like this-

```
public const double PI = 3.14xxxxxx;
public const double e = 2.xxxxxxxx;
```

And also I think values for `PI` and `e` are available in `Math` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

`const` variable must be assigned with value at compile time and the value cannot change at anytime.